# How do I find probabilities for certain values of a piecewise probability mass function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Consider the following probability mass function $f$:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{}\, x\lt 0\\
 \frac{x}{4}&\text{}\, 0\leq x\lt 1\\
 \frac{1}{2}+\frac{x-1}{4}&\text{}\, 1\leq x\lt 2\\
 \frac{11}{12}&\text{}\, 2\leq x\lt 3\\
 1&\text{}\, 3\leq x\\
\end{cases}
$

Lets say we want to find $P(X=i)$, for $i=1,2,3.$

For $P(X=1)$, we can calculate it as $P(X\leq1)-P(X<1)$, which in this case would be $f(1)-f(1^{-})$.

=$(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-1}{4}) - \frac{1}{4}$

=$\frac{1}{4}$

I understand the concept of $f(1)-f(1^{-})$, but why are we only considering $f(1^{-})$, and not $f(1^{+})$ in this case?

Comment: $f(1^+)=f(1)$.  Your second line should read $\frac{x}{4}$ for $0\le x \lt 1$.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Your second question is confusing, since the function is defined for $x\lt 1$.

Comment: perhaps $f$ is not probability mass function.It seems, $f$ is a cumulative distribution function